# Files I/O handling in Forth

Tags: forth, gforth

While learning Forth I have the following issue, concerning files I/O handling.

I am reading this tutorial https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/Files-Tutorial.html and trying to make sense of it. I have been able to deal with almost all of it (including copy-file), but I have a problem with the scan-file word.

I have the following foo.in input file:

```
$ cat foo.in
Hello world ...
Today is a beautiful day of November.
It is the 8th of November.
The text I search is here.
Actions speak louder than words.
$
```

I have this code (which runs with no problem) :

```
0 Value fd-in

256 Constant max-line
Create line-buffer  max-line 2 + allot

: open-input ( addr u -- )  r/o open-file throw to fd-in ;

: scan-file ( addr u -- )
begin
    line-buffer max-line fd-in read-line throw
while
    >r 2dup line-buffer r> compare 0=
until
else
drop
then
2drop ;

s" foo.in" open-input
```

Then I try this, expecting some results (of some kind):

```
s" The text I search is here" scan-file
```

I get the following:

```
s" The text I search is here" scan-file  ok
.s <0>  ok
```

Even if I change the string "The text I search is here" to some other arbitrary content; I see no difference in the result.

Can someone tell me what is supposed to happen and where I need to look.

At this point: scan-file seems to do nothing.

Comment: According to the stack diagram `scan-file ( addr u -- )`, this word returns nothing. What result do you expect?

Comment: OK. That's the question. Since scan-file is there, part of the tutorial, I assume it is meant for a reason. And I see nothing happening: this is precisely my problem. Can you help me make sense of scan-file ? Seeing the name I expected it would look for something but ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a problem in your tutorial. Also, the code does not contain anything specific to Gforth.

I would suggest the following variant for learning purposes:

```
0 value fd-in

256 constant max-line
max-line 2 +  chars  buffer: line-buffer

: open ( addr u -- )  r/o open-file throw to fd-in ;
: close ( -- ) fd-in if fd-in close-file throw 0 to fd-in then ;
: rewind ( -- ) 0 0 fd-in reposition-file throw ;

: scan ( addr u -- flag )
  rewind begin
    line-buffer max-line fd-in read-line throw
  while
    line-buffer swap  2over  search  nip nip
  until
    true
  then
  nip nip
;

s" foo.in" open
s" November" scan .
s" December" scan .
close
```

Comment: So, do you mean the tutorial is wrong ? And scan-file is non-sense code ?

Comment: I just had a look at the tutorial by your [link](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/Files-Tutorial.html). The section 3.27.3 "Scan file for a particular line" is ineffective because it does not provide insight into how `scan-file` can be useful. Perhaps this word is just a boilerplate and the reader is expected to change it to get a desired effect.

Comment: I tried your code in order to see how that works. But you must be using a Forth system slightly different from mine.
Because the code has an issue:

"max-line 2 +  chars  buffer: line-buffer"

leads to:

"max-line 2 +  chars  buffer: line-buffer
:5: Undefined word
max-line 2 +  chars  >>>buffer:<<< line-buffer
Backtrace:
$7F495DAABA68 throw
$7F495DAC1DB0 no.extensions
$7F495DAABD28 interpreter-notfound1"

Apart from that I was able to run it, replacing the line above by: "Create line-buffer  max-line 2 + allot".

Comment: I just show you a more modern way of defining a buffer using the standard [word `buffer:`](https://forth-standard.org/standard/core/BUFFERColon).  You are probably using Gforth 0.7.3, [released](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gforth/) about 10 years ago. In that case, just use your original line  defining a buffer via `create` and `allot` (as you have did). Or install a new [Gforth](https://gforth.org/) version.

Comment: Indeed I am  using Gforth 0.7.3. This is what I got installing the gforth package on Debian. I did not choose any specific version.

Comment: I have looked at your code for the scan word. Beside seeing how to handle the file I/O. I also learned a few other details. One is the way you mix up two types of loop structures (while-loop and until-loop). One other thing I am not sure how it works is the set of 2 lines (true then, after the until). I have tried to remove them, to make sure it was not some kind of misstype. But then it no longer works so it is obviously needed. But what means a "then" without an "if" ? This is something I have never seen before. Probably another forth trick I do not yet know ? :)

Comment: The original example in the tutorial contains the same `while` + `until` loop, and `then` without `if`.  See explanation of this control-flow construct in the Standard, section [Rationale / A.3.2.3.2 Control-flow stack](https://forth-standard.org/standard/rationale#paragraph.A.3.2.3.2)

Comment: Oh, you're right. I had somewhat overlooked that aspect of the code.